# (Efficiently) expose OpenFileDialog properties to COM Interop

Tags: c#, com-interop

I resell a product that uses VBS to enhance its forms. Showing an OpenFileDialog from VBS isn't trivial anymore since Vista (I believe, can't remember). However, with it I also optionally ship a .Net dll that uses COM Interop. So I thought it might be a nice idea to include a `FilePicker` in that.

In this assembly I currently have the following (example) code, which works fine:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("BlaBla.FilePicker")]
[Guid("xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IFilePicker))]
public class FilePicker : IFilePicker
{
    public string Show()
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

However, what I would like to do is expose (at least some) properties of the `OpenFileDialog` so that I can set initial locations and filters etc.

That is proving to be surprisingly hard. `OpenFileDialog` is a sealed class and its base class `FileDialog` is not meant to be inherited from.

I could simply expose the options by hardcoding them, in effect mimicking the `FileDialog` properties.

But that seems rather inefficient. Ideally, I would like to simply inherit fom some base class or interface and just implement that.

Is that feasible?

Comment: Sure, programmers prefer inheritance over encapsulation, it is less work.  But not an option here, encapsulation is a hard requirement.  You are using COM to use a .NET class that encapsulated a COM interface.  Yuck times three, but VBS doesn't let you use this COM interface directly since it is not Automation compatible.  Google "vbscript openfiledialog" to borrow somebody else's code, but it sure looks like you shouldn't use any of it :)

Comment: Not quite sure I follow you there. I just want an OpenFileDialog from my VBS (or any dialog that picks a file for that matter). My current scripts do it by writing and executing PowerShell 'on the fly', and VBS is my only option. I am looking into ways to offer an alternative. Are you saying I shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add arguments to IFilePicker.Show, eg:

```
public string Show(string initialDirectory)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = initialDirectory;
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return openFileDialog.FileName;
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Because it can take *a lot* of arguments. It would mean a ton of overloads.

Comment: You could also declare properties on IFilePicker that the caller can set before calling Show().

Comment: That is the idea, the question is how to include them without typing them all out? `FileDialog` has a lot of properties...

Comment: You're trying to optimize for the amount of typing you have to do to define your class?  That's a strange thing to optimize for.

Comment: I would not call it optimizing. It is just laziness on my part. There is a serious component to it though: I somehow expected there to be some kind of interface that I could implement, since this is such basic funcionality. I am simply surprised there isn't. That may just be me.